# Mongo - query, Embedded document not match except dot notation

Tags: mongodb, find

i am confuse.
here is the example:

```
MongoDB Enterprise > db.employee.find()
```

result:

```
{"_id":1002,"name":"Jack","address":{"previous":"Cresent Street","current":"234,Bald Hill Street","unit":"MongoDB" } }
```

I try this:

```
db.employee.find({address:{previous: "Cresent Street"}})

result: nothing returns
```

Next a try this:

```
 db.employee.find({"address.previous": "Cresent Street"})
```

result:

```
{"_id":1002,"name":"Jack","address":{"previous":"Cresent Street","current":"234,Bald Hill Street","unit":"MongoDB"}}
```

The question is wath is wrong with this?

i use
MongoDB shell version v4.2.7 installed
cmd db.version() 4.2.6
debian 10.4

thanks for your replies.

Comment: This is how MQL works.

Answer (score 1):

When you [Query on Embedded/Nested Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/index.html#query-on-embedded-nested-documents) using dotted field notation

```
{"address.previous": "Cresent Street"}
```

means find a document that containd an `address` field that contains a document whose `previous` field is equal to `"Cresent Street"`.

When you provide a subdocument like

```
{address:{previous: "Cresent Street"}}
```

this means to find a document that contains an `address` field whose content is exactly the document `{previous: "Cresent Street"}`, with no additional fields.  If you provide multiple fields in the subdocument, field order also matters.

Both of these queries are useful in specific scenarios, pick the one that does what you need in your situaion.

Comment: Thanks but if i make this
db.employee.find({"address" : { "previous" : "Cresent Street", "current" : "234,Bald Hill Street"}}) return nothing to.
I try find embedded document filter with other document and work.
I can't not know why in this document don't work. may encoding o something else

Comment: When you use the subdocument type of query, it has to be an exact match for the _entire_ subdocument, like `{address:{"previous":"Cresent Street","current":"234,Bald Hill Street","unit":"MongoDB" }}`, you cannot omit any fields, or it will no longer be an exact match.

Comment: Thanks, i took a not of this,.