# MongoDB Mongoose How to delete an object from an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   //Irrelevant code
   profile:
   { 
    requests: [{ sender: String, id: String,  hasSelected: Boolean, value: Boolean}]
   }
});
```

That object is to keep track of friend request, I want it to get completely deleted from the requests array once it has been accepted or declined. I have tried a whole bunch of stuff but nothing is deleting it. Currently have this code:

```
User.updateOne({ id: user.id },
              { "$pull": { "profile": { "requests": { "id": targetId } } }  },
              { "multi": true },
              function(err,status) {
                if(err){console.log("Could not delete the friend request");}
                else{ 
                  console.log("Sucessfully deleted friend request from: " + user.name);}
               }
              );
```

It always says it was deleted on the log, but when I check on mongoDB the request is still there.

Comment: You are using an exact document match instead of dotted field notation.  See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62010213/2282634

Comment: Thanks for the useful information, I tried with that syntax too and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try $elemMatch to remove the specific object.

```
 User.updateOne(
 { id: user.id },
 { $pull: { "profile.requests": { $elemMatch: { id: targetId } } } },
 { multi: true },
 function (err, status) {
 if (err) {
  console.log("Could not delete the friend request");
  } else {
  console.log("Sucessfully deleted friend request from: " + user.name);
 }
 }
 );
```

Comment: I tried that and it still doesn't delete the request. I also tried changing { id: user.id } to { "_id": user.id } and { _id: user.id } and { "id": user.id }. I am getting so discouraged, nothing is working. Have tried using findOne findMany findAndDelete and so many different combinations but nothing is working.

Comment: can you share the err and status after execute

Comment: I tried using update and I recieved a Deprication Warning. Here is what prints to the console
after I accept a friend request and print that users data to console:
```
{
  profile: {
    requests: [ [Object],  [Object] ]
  },
  _id: 5ed2b82cf24da00a60b3d893,
  //Whole bunch of irrelevant info....
--v: 2
}
Sucessfully deleted friend request from: User1
```
There were 2 friend requests, as you can see they are still there.