# MongoDB Unable to delete item from array

Tags: mongodb

I've been at this problem for the whole day and I just can't seem to grasp what is the problem with $pull method in MongoDB, I am trying to remove an item from my shopping cart and I always get this:

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

*I want to remove item from my array 'products' in my schema with **title** of BTC*

My 'carts' collection data in MongoDB:

```
{
    "userId": {
        "$oid": "5f940f8876ad3e073a2e1e8b"
    },
    "__v": 0,
    "products": [{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5fc6888b1e10cd1b01382ec2"
        },
        "title": "BTC",
        "price": 10000,
        "amount": 6
    }],
    "totalPrice": 60000
}
```

My past 2 attempts:

```
db.carts.update({},
    { $pull: { "products": { title: 'BTC'} } } )
db.carts.update({ _id : '5fc6888b42d86bad7dafa319'},
    { $pull: { "products": { title: 'BTC'} } } )
```

*Why don't I even get nMatched ?*

Comment: Are you connected to the same database? Try `use <db-name>`

Comment: Yes I am connected to the database

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62010213/2282634

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think the problem is `_id` is not a string

```
ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

const id = new ObjectId("idHere")
db.carts.update(
    { _id : id },
    {$pull:{ "products":{ title:'BTC' } }} 
)
```

And the first example won't match because it's looking for an exact match.

[you can experiment here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QCywnhgHBAj)

Comment: Thank you very much, problem was that it wasn't ObjectId. Question about that, should I use ObjectId's usually or should I stick to custom String ids ?

Comment: As long as `_id` are produced by MongoDB i think the only way is to use ObjectID. You're welcome @Frskn

Comment: Also, you could check mongoose, it has functions prepackaged for that (and I believe mongodb driver hasnt). For example https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById (there is findByIdAndUpdate too!) @Frskn

Comment: I am using it already, thank you, I test first on terminal before testing further in express