# MongoDb search for all documents where some filed inside array of array is equals to some value

Tags: mongodb

I need to perform a filter, through the azure portal, on a MongoDb collection, I need to find all documents where the field `SystemServerId` is equals to 125104

this is a basic version of the document:

```
{
    "_id" : "613a7c1ce007cf00167cd07a",
    "UserId" : 334645,
    "Events" : [
        {
            "UserManagerId" : 334645,
            "Method" : "MethodXXX",
            "EventLogs" : [
                {
                    "Classe" : "ClassXXX"
                }
            ],
            "SystemTracer" : {
                "UsersServers" : [
                    {
                        "SystemServerId" : 125104
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I read some documents on MongoDb site, about aggregation, but, I didn't managed how to make this filter, what I tried:

`{ Events: { "SystemTracer.UsersServers": { SystemServerId:125104 } } }`

`{ "Events": { "SystemTracer": { "UsersServers": { SystemServerId:125104 } } } }`

And a lot of variations of this filter...
Well, I can filter the documents on collection ?

Comment: So close.  Try `{"Events.SystemTracer.UsersServers.SystemServerId":125104}`

Comment: For more explanation see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62010213/2282634

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$elemMatch`

```
db.collection.find({Events:{$elemMatch:{"SystemTracer.UsersServers":{$elemMatch:{SystemServerId:125104}}}}})
```